# Understanding usage of denen

Tags: grammar-identification, relative-pronoun

> Konzept des fairen Handels ist es, Handelsprozesse vornehmlich zwischen Entwicklungs und Industrieländern so zu gestalten, dass den Erzeugern ein Mindestpreis für ihre Produkte gezahlt wird, der über denen des herkömmlichen Handels liegt.

I am trying to understand the usage of denen in the above. When I look up denen usage on google, I find that it's supposed to be relative pronoun for dative plural [eg](https://www.reddit.com/r/German/comments/169v0s5/help_with_denen_and_in_denen/). But, as far as I understand normally the relative pronoun comes right after the comma, or after a preposition which comes after the comma. What happend here?

Comment: I would recommand that you consult a dictionary instead of googling, because the sources you find there may not be reliable.

Comment: How would I use a dictionary to answer this question @RHa

Comment: How could one use a dictionary to find out about a word such as *denen*? Maybe by looking it up? A good dictionary would have told you that it is a pronoun and not only a relative pronoun.

Comment: @RHa - For example English Wiktionary has a separate entry for "denen" where it's listed as a pronoun, relative or demonstrative. It also tells you to look up the main entry "der", which has the article and both pronouns, along with all their respective inflections. German dictionaries probably won't include a separate entry because German speakers are expected to already know the main form is "der".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify. I introduce the adverb *darüber* for that purpose:

> Ein Preis, der **darüber** liegt.

As you can see, that *der* is a relative pronoun referring to *ein Preis*. No further relative pronouns needed. Let's expand that *darüber* a bit. The adverb becomes a full adverbial:

> Ein Preis, der **über den üblichen Preisen** liegt.

Here the dative is introduced by the preposition *über*. That argument *die üblichen Preise* ist what we expand next. Let's introduce a reference as a genitive attribute:

> Ein Preis, der **über den üblichen Preisen des Marktes** liegt.

And finally, we can reduce *den üblichen Preisen* to the pronoun *der* in dative plural, as that may be guessed from context with that genitive attribute:

> Ein Preis, der **über denen des Marktes** liegt.

And it's the same in your example. That *denen* refers to context. It's a method for creating standalone genitive attributes, so you don't have to repeat yourself too often.

Let's translate that into English:

> A price that is **above those of the market**.

It's obvious now, isn't it?

Comment: And do you think that's an acceptable sentence? I don't really find anything that "denen" can refer to. The author should just have written "den Preisen".

Comment: I think it is very acceptable, yes. It's completely clear that it's a comparison to *Mindestpreis* in the original sentence.

Comment: How is adverbial differ from adverbs?

Comment: "e can reduce den üblichen Preisen to the pronoun der in dative plural" but you made it as denen

Comment: but overall I think I got what you mean

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I don't feel that "denen" can refer to only the "Preis" in "Mindestpreis".

Comment: @tryst with freedom Adverbs are a special one-word kind of adverbial. The other common way to form an adverbial is with a noun phrase lead by a preposition. And in German, there's also adverbial accusatives. That's nouns in accusative that aren't an accusative object.

Comment: @tryst with freedom *denen* is the dative plural of the pronoun *der*: https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Demonstrativpronomen_der_die_das

Answer (score 3):

While "denen" can indeed also be a relative pronoun, it is not in this case. It is a demonstrative pronoun: "... which lies above **those**/**the ones** of the conventional market". The words I wrote in bold are the part that "denen" translates to; it is really the same construct as in this translation.

Comment: There is a lot of overlap between definite articles and relative and demonstrative pronouns in German, so you have to use context to figure out which one is meant. The fact that it's not right after a comma is a clue that it's not a relative pronoun. You can rule out an article because all those inflections have three letters, so demonstrative.